# Trying to take screen grabs using iphone 7plus/8 in xcode 9 to upload to appstore but sim won't give me "100%"

Tags: swift, xcode

I'd like to upload my app to the appstore.
Just need some screen grabs 1242 x 2208.
In xcode 8/simulator i could set the size of the simulator to 50%, 100%, etc. and then take the screen shot.
But with xcode 9/sim the options are either 50% or actual size and while 100%, 200% are still there they are disabled. SO my screen grabs are like 500 x 700 or something similar.
And I have an old 5s so that won't help anyone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use my iPhoneSE and iPad Mini for my screenshot submissions. Never had any problem. Here's the steps:

- Connect device to Mac.
- Open `QuickTime`, choosing menu option `File | New Movie Recording`. (This sets up a “perfect” StatusBar.)
- ALSO: If screenshot uses UIActivityController, turn Airdrop OFF.
- Select device, take pics.
- Import to Mac. (Airdrop, tethered connection to Photos or iPhoto, etc.)
- Using `Preview`, resize iPad screenshots to 2732 x 2048, and iPhone screenshots to 2208 x 1242.

*Note: My sizes are for portrait, but landscape works just the same.*

Comment: Appears to be a bug with xcode 9 re: the simulator and once it's changed once eg to 50% can't change it again.

Comment: Understood. I wanted to give you an alternative that bypasses the simulator and should work with iPhone 5s. Hopefully, there's a RADR for the Xcode bug.